# Where can I download prism template pack for visual studio 2019? Seems like all the links only support 2022

Tags: templates, prism

I currently have vs 2019 installed and I still haven't raised enough cash to purchase vs 2022. Please can I get a download link from an old source?

I tried downloading the file from csdn.net but it's almost impossible to create a free account. "https://download.csdn.net/download/sinat_36203916/16292210?spm=1001.2101.3001.6650.8&utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-download-2%7Edefault%7EBlogCommendFromBaidu%7ERate-8-16292210-blog-124120014.pc_relevant_3mothn_strategy_recovery&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-download-2%7Edefault%7EBlogCommendFromBaidu%7ERate-8-16292210-blog-124120014.pc_relevant_3mothn_strategy_recovery&utm_relevant_index=12"

Comment: [VS 2022 **Community Edition**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is entirely **FREE** to use - even for commercial usage ....

Answer (score 1):

You can download lastest compatible VS2019 Prism Template Pack at this link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/BrianLagunas/vsextensions/PrismTemplatePack/2.3.0/vspackage